# how to parse a string to a function from a textbox to the onclick event

Tags: vba, function, ms-access-2016

Hi Guys I have a function called PlayVideo which works in the 'onclick event' from a button on a form.

'The onclick event' is `=PlayVideo("C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Lake.wp4")`

I need to replace the path name in the 'onclick event' with whatever path name is in the TBox1 at the time.

The Tbox1 is formatted so the string is the same ie:("H:\Stormy Weather.mp4")

I'm just unsure how to attach it so it works in the 'onclick event' or as a sub.

Thanks any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just use `=PlayVideo([TBox1])`?

Comment: yes thank you for that I didn't have the () around the field name but the function allows for an error routine and couldn't work out how to add  /fullscreen after it without quotes. opening media player full screen mode doesn't seem to work, well calling it from here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Change th button's *OnClick* event to "[Event Procedure]". This will create a routine in the module behind file like the one shown below. Paste the rest.

```
Private Sub YourButtonName_Click()
    Dim file_ As String
        file_ = Me.TBox1.Value

    'Validate file exists
    If Len(Dir(file_)) > 0 Then
        PlayVideo file_
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks worked a treat one more thing how would I add  /fullscreen to end of it without quotes.

Comment: didnt give fullscreen anyway thought vbMaximizedFocus in the function would of worked too have to keep looking but thanks again for your help at least it works now.